# Dozer mapping non-Generic Collections to properties

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, dozer, object-object-mapping

I have some class structure as follows. These classes are hibernate classes so I cant change them.

```
//assume all getters & setters are present 
public class Order{ 
    private Customer customer; 
} 

public class Customer{ 
    // non generics set 
    private Set nameParts; 
} 

public class NamePart{ 
    private String id; 
    private String name; 
}

// target class
public class OrderShippingDetail{ 
    private String firstName; 
}
```

mappying file

```
<mapping> 
    <class-a>Order</class-a> 
    <class-b>OrderShippingDetail</class-b> 
    <field> 
        <a>customer.nameParts[0].name</a> 
        <b>firstName</b> 
    </field> 
</mapping>
```

But this mapping of **customer.nameParts[0].name** dosent work as the dozer dosent know the object in the set. is there any work around.

If this can only be done by custom converter, a sample code template hint is appreciated.

Comment: so you're trying to map the first element in the set nameParts to the firstName? Sets are unordered so the first element in nameParts will not always be the same...

Comment: yeah I know that, but the original developer left it with set which has only one element and thats the whole customer name (not just a part). basically I want to access any one element present in that set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going through the documentation and found that for non generic collections during deep mapping one can specify the objects using

```
<field> 
    <a>customer.nameParts[0].name</a> 
    <b>firstName</b> 
    <a-deep-index-hint>com.example.Customer, com.example.NamePart</a-deep-index-hint>
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

go one level deeper. like this

```
<mapping> 
    <class-a>Order</class-a> 
    <class-b>OrderShippingDetail</class-b> 
    <field> 
        <a>customer.nameParts[0]</a> 
        <b>this</b> 
    </field> 
</mapping>

<mapping>
    <class-a>{class of object @ nameparts[0]}</class>
    <class-b>OrderShippingDetail</class-b>
    <field><a>name</a><b>firstname</b></field>
</mapping>
```

this works as a work-around. I've used this trick to make it work at some places.

Comment: I dont know what that **<b>this</b>** does during mapping. can you explain or give a link for that?